# Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object when generating PDF from product page

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to generate a PDF from a table in my database using the FPDF plugin from within the `product` post type. I need the query to only return the data for the the post->ID of the current product.

I've using a function called `output_pdf` which is called when you click a button in the admin section.

However, when I try using the `global $post` and call the `$post->ID` I'm getting the error `Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object`

If i manually enter an ID into the query like so `'wc_lottery_log WHERE lottery_id ="72")` it works perfectly.

How do I pass the ID of the current post into the SQL query?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'my_function_with_wc_functions' );
function my_function_with_wc_functions() {
if( isset($_POST['generate_posts_pdf'])) {
    output_pdf();
}
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'as_fpdf_add_custom_box');
function as_fpdf_add_custom_box()
{
    $screens = ['product'];
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
            'as_fpdf_box_id',           // Unique ID
            'Entry List',  // Box title
            'as_fpdf_create_admin_page',  // Content callback, must be of type callable
            $screen,                   // Post type
            'normal'                  // Priority
        );
    }
}

function output_pdf() {

    global $post;
    global $wpdb;

        if ( $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT lottery_id FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'wc_lottery_log WHERE lottery_id = %d', $post->ID ) ) ) {

      $log = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'wc_lottery_log WHERE lottery_id=%d', $post->ID ) );

      global $pdf;
      $title_line_height = 10;
      $content_line_height = 8;

      $pdf->AddPage();
      $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 42 );
      $pdf->Write(20, 'Atomic Smash FPDF Tutorial');

      foreach( $log as $row ) {

          $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 22 );
          $pdf->Write($title_line_height, $post->post_title);

          // Add a line break
          $pdf->Ln(15);

          // Post Content
          $pdf->Ln(10);
          $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 12 );
          $pdf->WriteHTML($row->ticketid);
        }

    }

    $pdf->Output('D','atomic_smash_fpdf_tutorial.pdf');
    exit;
}


function as_fpdf_create_admin_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Generate Entry List</h1>
    <p>Click below to generate a pdf all all lottery entries. </p>
      <form method="post" id="as-fdpf-form">
        <button class="button button-primary" type="submit" name="generate_posts_pdf" value="generate">Generate PDF from Competiion Entries</button>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Using `global`, as you do, should do the trick if it is indeed a global variable, and if it has the correct value. It seems to  have a value but it's not an object. Maybe you should `var_dump($post)` before running the query, and see what it actually contains. At first sight, it looks like the problem is neither related to WordPress nor to SQL, but simply a small misinterpretation of the value of $post.

Comment: Hi GolezTrol, I added var_dump into the output_pdf() function before the query and it didn't display anything. However, If i add the var_dump($post) into the as_fpdf_create_admin_page() it prints out the post object. Is it because the output_pdf() is being called on the button click and isn't being passed correctly?

Comment: Could be that the $post object is not properly initialized in that situation, but I can't tell exactly why. The code you posted doesn't show the initialization of $post at all.

Comment: I think you're right. When i changed the add_action to add_action( 'woocommerce_init') I can call global $woocommerce. How would I init the global $post? This code is within a Wordpress plugin

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WordPress, but there is [some documentation on $post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post) that might make sense to you. Apparently there is some [initialization (The Loop)](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) going on in which those variables are available. Most likely `output_pdf` is called somewhere outside of that loop. But like I said, I don't know enough about WordPress to give proper advice how to solve this.